# Automatically set the created and updated date with squeryl?

Tags: scala, squeryl

I remember seeing a trait that will automatically add the created and updated dates when using either lift's Record or Mapper ORMs.

The question is, is there a similar thing for Squeryl to automatically set the date/time the record was inserted and, less importantly, the last date/time it was updated?

If not, is it possible to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing trait you can mix in to do it, but if you are using 0.9.5-SNAPSHOT you can create your own using Squeryl's lifecycle callbacks.  Take a look at this message for more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/squeryl/lifecycle/squeryl/8FY7n0DN5fs/O2O8OhqVPSUJ. If you run into any trouble post a message to the group and we'll do what we can to help you out.